# socket.io and .Net socket server

Tags: comet, websocket

Excuse me if the question sounds silly but I have to ask. Is there a server side alternative to Node.js written in C#? I need a client framework to fully utilize Web Sockets but AFAIK IE doesn't support Web Sockets and nor will it support in it's next version. socket.io uses Web Sockets if available and falls back to BOSH if not. So I will try to connect to a socket server that is running on .Net Framework.

What are my alternatives?

Comment: Ok, I wrote my own socket server and it works like a charm.

Comment: If you answer your own question with a link to a github project I promise to upvote your answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

Excuse me for raising this thread from the dead - my friend and I just posted a server-side websocket server for C#: https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets

It's fast, it's scalable, and doesn't do everything socket.io does, on purpose: it provides websockets and a flash fallback, which keeps it very lean and efficient. I see you've already done your own stuff, but check it out; and hopefully it'll help others on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Might be an answer to an old question, but I'll write here in case other finds this question using a search engine. Have a look at SignalR (http://signalr.net/) for that abstraction. For a nice post on what SignalR is please read Scott Hanselman's post http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx.

Comment: SignalR doesn't utilize Web Sockets because it runs ontop of .net and windows that don't support Web Sockets on the server side.
SignalR will use serverSideEvents on all the browsers except IE which will utilize Forever-Frame.

Comment: @RegisteredUser that's not entirely correct. SignalR will use WebSockets if both the client and server supports it. SignalR supports multiple hosting options, but the most widely used as of yet is of course IIS. Thus, SignalR will support WebSockets if the SignalR host supports WebSockets. IIS on Windows Server 8 supports WebSockets. The current version when writing this (and a few versions back) use the best transport method available on both client and server from the following list: WebSockets, Server Sent Events, Forever Frame and finally Long Polling.